# Recycler view padding between view not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to put a padding between each view in a Recycler view. But it's not working.

The Xml code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_schedule"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                           
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    tools:itemCount="2"
    tools:listitem="@layout/layout_schedule">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

The output result :

recycler view out from AVD

[image: recycler view out from AVD]

I upgrade android studio from 3.0 to 3.1 today and on the 3.0 the xml code shown above was working.

I'm using the version 26 of the android support dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is not working? what did you try?

Comment: The padding between ly 2 card view in my recycler view. I want a space between them. I'm currently doing a roolback to android 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as designed. Your code is applying an 8dp padding to a recycler view, not to it's child views. You should apply a **margin** to your `layout_schedule` to achieve your goal.

Or, if you're using a CardView as a container for your item view, you can set it's `app:cardUseCompatPadding` attribute to `true` and it will gain a spacing too.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

         ...................
       your item layout structure
         ...................

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @GuillaumeEbert Glad to hear it. If it was helpful, you could mark this answer as right.

Comment: Kyrylchuck Done !